# API end point returning "Authorization has been denied for this request." when sending bearer token

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I've followed a tutorial to protect a Web API with OAuth in C#.

I'm doing some tests and so far I've been able to get the access token successfully from `/token`. I'm using a Chrome extension called "Advanced REST Client" to test it.

```
{"access_token":"...","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":86399}
```

This is what I get back from `/token`. Everything looks good.

My next request is to my test API Controller:

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Social")]
    public class SocialController : ApiController
    {
      ....


        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Schedule(SocialPost post)
        {
            var test = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User;

            ....
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

The request is a `POST` and has the header:

```
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXTOKEHEREXXXXXXX
```

I get: `Authorization has been denied for this request.` returned in JSON.

I tried doing a GET as well and I get what I would expect, that the method isn't supported since I didn't implement it.

Here is my Authorization Provider:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (var repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            IdentityUser user = await repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));

        context.Validated(identity); 

    }
}
```

Any help would be great. I'm not sure if it is the request or the code that is wrong.

edit:
Here is my `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Issue is pretty simple:
**Change order of your OWIN pipeline**.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureOAuth(app);
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

For OWIN pipeline order of your configuration quite important. In your case, you try to use your Web API handler before the OAuth handler. Inside of it, you validate your request, found you secure action and try to validate it against current `Owin.Context.User`. At this point this user not exist because its set from the token with OAuth Handler which called later.

Comment: How would you do this if you're not registering WebApi in the pipeline? I'm just working with the default Web API template. GET requests work fine, POST requests give me 401. While the token is the same.

Comment: This caught me out! Thanks for taking the time to post this answer.

Comment: I wasted few hours after refactoring trying to find a reason for this issue.

Comment: omg I wont post the hours I wasted trying to figure this out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a claim with this schema:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role
```

best thing to do is to use the pre-defined set of claims:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
```

You can find `ClaimTypes` in `System.Security.Claims`.

Another thing you have to consider is filter roles in your Controller/Action:

```
[Authorize(Roles="User")]
```

You can find a simple sample app, self-hosted owin with a jquery client [here](https://github.com/Leftyx/OwinWebApiBearerToken).

Comment: I added: `identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));` to no avail. Does it matter that user is capital? I added this before I saw your comment. I wouldn't think that would matter. I'll check out your link.

Comment: That is a constant and can be anything.

Comment: I tried changing `[Authorize]` to include the role in my controller, but I'm still not getting it to authorize. I created a fresh user in the role "User" and got a fresh token successfully. Updated my code above with your suggested change.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the version of "**System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt"** that co-exists with the other Owin assemblies is not proper.

In case you're using "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version 2.1.0, you ought to be using the "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" assembly of version 3.0.2.

From the package manager console, try:

```
Update-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt -Version 3.0.2
```